# Windows 7 Eject Drive ejects internal keyboard and trackpad

Tags: windows-7, usb, macbook-pro

I'm running Windows 7 on a Macbook Pro via Bootcamp. Recent (most recent windows update, maybe?) I started having this issue:

[image]

The external drive (with two partitions) plugged into one of the two USB ports gets nested underneath the keyboard/trackpad, so I can't eject it. If I eject the trackpad/keyboard, I can no longer interface with the computer, unless I plug a USB mouse into the other USB port. The other USB port does not behave this way with an external Drive. Any ideas as to why this is happening, or how to correct it?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't click on the word "PORTABLE HD (K:)" to eject just that?  Your image is how a composite device is normally displayed, but you can eject each item individually normally.

Comment: @Paul no, I can't select either of the two drives. I can't normally, either. Here's what the drive looks like plugged into the other usb port. http://i.imgur.com/NyLgn.png

Comment: Odd.  Does it do the same thing with a standard usb flash drive - like a single partition off-the-shelf one?  Does it still appear as a composite of the trackpad rather than its own device?  I suspect it is how the usb host in the keyboard has been implemented (as not really a usb host)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. :(